# Does the reaction between phosphorus and chlorine produce phosphorus trichloride or phosphorus pentachloride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Phosphorus has two covalent compounds it can form with chlorine, where it is a single, central atom bonded to chlorine, which are phosphorus trichloride and phosphorus pentachloride.  Because of this, I am not sure as to whether phosphorus will react with chlorine to form the trichloride and the pentachloride.

I am thinking that it would probably be more likely for it to form the trichloride, since it is more favorable for phosphorus to not have an expanded octet, but does the amount of chlorine gas in relation to the phosphorus (excess or not) play a role in what compound will be formed?

Comment: Yes, it will depend on concentration of chlorine

Comment: vide https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorus_trichloride#Preparation & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorus_trichloride#Preparation

Comment: Sir Humphry Davy had mentioned that when he burned phosphorus in chlorine gas, he obtained a clear liquid (phosphorus trichloride) and a white solid (phosphorus pentachloride) - reference 15 of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorus_trichloride).